# How do I create a R file that stores my own syntax color in R?

Tags: r

Currently, I have manually chosen the syntax color under "Preference" in my old laptop to be as follow (see below):

Now I have a new laptop and I just installed R in it, I want to have the same syntax color and I do not want to do this manually. Is there a way such that I can export a file that contains information (or code) about my syntax color in  old laptop and then I can import this file into the R into my new laptop  ?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to Rgui?

Comment: Looks like you're on a Mac and using the standard R GUI? You can access the preferences via the terminal: `defaults read org.R-project.R`. Most likely you can just copy over the `~/Library/Preferences/org.R-project.R.plist` file.

Comment: Yes. I am using Rgui

Comment: @MrFlick And Yes my old laptop is Mac. Where should I copy that file to, if my new laptop is Window ?

Comment: The GUIs for the different OSes are completely different. You can't move a Mac preferences file to a Windows machine. The GUI is outside the R language itself.